# Send deep copy of object across process boundary in C++

Tags: c++, linux, serialization, pipe

I have a situation where I have an object of a class in C++, which needs to be send across process boundaries (process 1 to process 2) using Linux pipes. I searched online on how to do serialization in C++. I found [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html), but it requires some changes in the class. In my situation I cannot change the class.

This class has a lot of pointers, and the nesting continues to 3 levels (Class 1 has pointer 1 of type Class 2-> Class 2 has pointer 2 of type Class 3 -> Class 3 has pointer 3 of type class 4 -> Class 4). Is there any way I can send this object using pipes so that it can be recreated in the second process ?

Thanks.

Comment: "In my situation I cannot change the class" ... declaration? Or can you not even modify the implementation?  It's unrealistic to provide a general serialization solution using only the class' public methods.

Comment: @BrianCain I cannot change class implementation

Comment: Isn't this a reason for why XML were invented? And if you don't like XML then try JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to serialize the class somehow. How exactly is your choice, but you can do so in a format like [`JSON`](http://json.org/), or `XML`, or some kind of binary format you decide on. Without seeing any more details on your class, there's not much else to add.

Another option might be to use [Shared memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory) segments to store the class, but that comes with issues with pointer math, concurrency and other complications.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered an application of the [Memento pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern)?  You could create a class or classes to handle the details of how to serialize the object (either to text or binary).

The class you create to save objects would also know how to instantiate new objects from the serialization format you choose in the next process.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to do some sort of serialization, because you can't copy-construct across a pipe or anything like that. If you can't change the class then your only choice is to write an external function or class that uses your top level class's public API to get all the pieces and serialize that data. Then on the other end you'll have to reconstruct it from the stream.